# Unable to read json file using pd.read_json or json.load due to character. Way to read json as string to find and replace? or load properly?

Tags: python, json, data-cleaning

```
  "error": null,
  "data": [
```

The above line *"error": null,* is what is giving me an issue. When I manually delete it from the file I don't have an issue, but unfortunately, that won't work for the problem I am trying to solve.

Below are the various errors I receive when the line is kept in the json file.

when using pd.read_json

```
data = pd.read_json(file_name)
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

when using json.load or json.loads

```
with open(file_name) as file:
data = json.load(file)
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

when using ast.literal_eval(file_name.read())

```
with open(file_name) as file:
data = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

I'm guessing it's because of some bizarre invisible uni-code character or whatever.

Anyway to read the json in as text and find and replace then go back to json? or any way to read the json in?

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you have any specifics/need more info.

Comment: No, it's telling you that it's not valid JSON

Comment: `null` should become `None` but it hasn't

Comment: forgot to include the error when I try json.dumps() "TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable"

Comment: @roganjosh yes from what I've read I was expecting the null to become None, but it's not, I don't need the line so if a way to skip over it that works. Not sure how to process the file as it only comes as a JSON file and the client can't provide it (or refuses to) in any other format

Comment: ` "data": ["` is obviously wrong. Can you work out a small working example where it fails? `json.loads('{"error":null,\n"data":[0]}')` works for me. If there is some invisible character, it didn't make to the data pasted here.

Comment: @tdelaney apologies didn't paste directly from the file additionally can't share the rest of the JSON as it's sensitive information.

Comment: @tdelaney 
```{
  "error": null,
  "data": [
```
this is copy and pasted directly from the JSON

Comment: Using just that fragment I get `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 32 (char 31)`. Did your error include numbers like this? You could pull a small part of that file, scrub out anything compromising, and post that. We need text that fails to see what to do next.

Comment: Suppose there was some strange strange unicode character in there. You could read small amounts of data in binary mode around where that fragment is, and see if there is anything weird.

Answer (score 0):

One Simple and quick solution will be:

replace:

> null

with

> 'null'

and then parse/eval null value as None or np.nan whatever way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for delay to answering. roganjosh was correct, it was not a valid JSON file. Solution was converting it into text and then removing *"error": null,* from the text, then converting back to JSON.